LTSpice Circuit will not run due to curly bracket error and undefined symbol error
When I run my circuit I keep getting a undefined symbol error. I am fairly new to LTSpice and I have searched the internet but I could not find any website to help me understand what the error below is telling me. The circuit I am creating is a circuit to detect an overcurrent event. I am doing a DC sweep to find when the comparators will output a logical high.

Questionable use of curly braces in "b§g1 1 2 i=limit({v(1,2)/(v(3,4)*{r_1v})},1e6,-1e6)"
    Error: undefined symbol in: "[v](1,2)/(v(3,4)*(r_1v))"
Questionable use of curly braces in "b§g27 0 27 i=-55.0u+v(1)*{7.16u*v(5001)}+v(2)*{7.16u*v(5001)} "
    Error: undefined symbol in: "7.16u*[v](5001)"
Questionable use of curly braces in "b§g27 0 27 i=-55.0u+v(1)*(7.16u*v(5001))+v(2)*{7.16u*v(5001)} "
    Error: undefined symbol in: "7.16u*[v](5001)"
Questionable use of curly braces in "b§g27 0 27 i=-55.0u+v(1)*{7.16u*v(5001)}+v(2)*{7.16u*v(5001)} "
    Error: undefined symbol in: "7.16u*[v](5001)"
Questionable use of curly braces in "b§g27 0 27 i=-55.0u+v(1)*(7.16u*v(5001))+v(2)*{7.16u*v(5001)} "
    Error: undefined symbol in: "7.16u*[v](5001)"


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try finding which library file(s) generate the errors and edit them to replace each offending curly brace with a parentheses of matching direction.
